# Custom Cell can't display in Table view in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface MasterViewController ()
@end

@implementation MasterViewController

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
          self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
  }
  return self;
 }

   - (void)dealloc
   {
      [_detailViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
    }

   - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];

     }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
     {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
      }



     #pragma mark - Table View

        - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         {
               return 1;
         }

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
         {
                return 5;
          }
         -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    return 100.0;
         }

       // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
             static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
             CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
          {
               cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

          }

    cell.cellDate.text=@"date";
     cell.cellDescription.text =@"Description";
     cell.cellImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
      cell.cellTitle.text = @"Title";
      return cell;


    }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
}
    else
   {

   }
  }

@end
```

---

### .h file

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "CustomCell.h"
    #import "XMLStringFile.h"

  @class DetailViewController;

 @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController{


 }

 @property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
 @property(strong,nonatomic)CustomCell *customCell;
  @end
```

---

CustomCell.h

---

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell{

   IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageview;
   IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle; 
   IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescription;
   IBOutlet UILabel *cellDate;

 }
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageview;
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescription;
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellDate;

 @end
```

---

CustomCell.m

---

```
      #import "CustomCell.h"

      @implementation CustomCell

    @synthesize cellDate;
   @synthesize cellDescription;   
  @synthesize cellImageview;
 @synthesize cellTitle;

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
 }
@end
```

---

> This is my both class 
>    here Problem is in tableview data of the customcell cant Display onlt white screen.
>    Here i work in ios with masterdetails view template..
>    here i have also added m file in compile source
>    Customcell.xib size is 300X100 
>    Here my output 
>    My xib file as below
>   [image: This is my CustomCell.xib]

[image: This is my output Screen]

please help me to solve problem

Comment: it seems you use your custom cells like a standard `UITableCellView` objects. where is the `.xib` file for your custom cell anyway?

Comment: Not UITableCellView its UITableViewCell :D

Comment: @TheTiger, you are right. :) but the point is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(cell == nil)
 {
     NSArray *outlets = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil]];
     for(id obj in outlets)
     {
         if([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
         {
             cell = (CustomCell *)obj;
         }
     }
 }
```

If your `CustomCell` is made via `XIB` then Write this Code where your cell is `nil`.

**EDIT:-**
This may be the cause - I think you haven't changed your `CustomCell`'s class name. Follow these steps -

1. Take a `XIB` with name `CustomCell.xib` then delete its view.
2. Take a `UITableViewCell` and set its height and structure according to you.
3. Select `File's Owner` and change its class name to `CustomCell`, Same thing do with `UITableViewCell`... select it and change its class name to `CustomCell`.
4. Now connect all `subView`'s **IBOutLets**.

**Note:-** *Select `IBOutLets` by right clicking on `UITableViewCell` not from `File's Owner`*.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MasterViewController_iPhone" nib but the view outlet was not set

Comment: Seems like you haven't set `MasterViewController`'s view **IBOutLet**. You changed its name your self so you will have to set xib IBOutLet and its class first. Open `MasterViewController_iPhone` then changed its class to your `ViewController` class after that right click on `File's Owner` **ctrl+drag** view to XIB's View.

Comment: in my MasterViewController_iPhone.xib contain only one objects that is Tableview no window or simple view is there, so i have to changed the class name to UITableview?????????

Comment: in connection Inspector of tableview two unclicked button 1 datasource and delegate my quection is where to drag this property

Comment: No dude No ... error what you getting because of wrong view connection. Your xib class name should be same your `UIViewController` name for which you're loading this nib. `MasterViewController_iPhone.xib` there is wrong class name. Please correct it. And I think you need to learn basics first.

Comment: ooops i geting i developed universal app that for both iphone and ipad i getting whats my problem....

Comment: Okayzz ... Next time be aware :) ***Coding is like a Lover who love and take care about it and who dont its ghost for them :)***

Answer (score 2):

If the cell is designed in a nib then you need to load the cell from the nib.

This actually has support in `UIKit` since iOS 5

What you need to do is register your nib with the `UITableView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Customcell" bundle:nil]   
       forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

  //...
}
```

Now your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` just needs to look like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
  CustomCell *cell = (id)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

  cell.cellDate.text        = @"date";
  cell.cellDescription.text = @"Description";
  cell.cellImageview.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook.png"];
  cell.cellTitle.text       = @"Title";

  return cell;
}
```

**NB**

Make sure to remember to set `CustomCell` as the reuseIdentifier in the xib

**Some other observations**

- Really you should be using ARC for a new project.
- `@synthesize` is implicit so not required in most cases
- It's probably a bad idea to `#import "CustomCell.h"` in `MasterViewController.h`.
  You should move this to the `.m` and use a forward declaration in the `.h` instead - `@class CustomCell;`
- You also do not need to declare the backing ivars for properties as these will also be generated by the compiler e.g. you don't need to declare the following

  ```
  @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageview;
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle; 
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellDescription;
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellDate;
  }
  ```

Comment: i fill good for getting suggestion from you because of you are good experience person that i hope,after seeing your stackscore,

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Customcell" bundle:nil];
   [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
}
```